# how can I re-write every request to a file except some specific ones in htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I use htaccess to re-wright URL, but I am not an expert in it. In the beginning I wanted to replace index.php with default.php. So i re-write every request to default.php by:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^  blog/default.php
```

But then I needed to re-write some specific URL differently. For example I needed to re-write 
`example.com/sitemap to sitemap.xml` but the first rule is over-ruling this one. I tried with all the answers on stack and other website but no solution. I want to modify my first rule so that if I want to add specific exception it would also get followed.

Comment: You could use a negative lookahead with alterations. `^(?!sitemap to sitemap.xml|otherpage.php)`

Answer (score 0):

Apply rules using a [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) directive:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?(sitemap|else)/?$
RewriteRule . blog/default.php
```